# XCode 6.4 - debug console is not printing complete log

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, xcode6

When I print a NSArray object value which has nearly 50 objects, debug console is not printing all the 50 objects. Log is getting truncated.

I am facing this issue only in XCode 6.4.

Comment: You need to add way more details to this bug.

Comment: Are you using print() in Swift, or NSLog(). print is not thread safe, you should only use it on the main thread. Also, if you print 40 massive images, some internal print buffer may overflow. Write a few, then dispatch a message to the main thread, print the next 10, dispatch another, print the next 10...